# CodeIgniter get_where order_by

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am tring to use get_where and order_by like so...

```
$query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_name, $where)->order_by('birth_date', 'ASC');
```

but got this error...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::order_by() in C:\xampp\htdocs\OAWA\application\models\Member_model.php on line 82
```

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Code Igniter do you use? The doc says: `Note: order_by() was formerly known as orderby(), which has been removed.`

Comment: I think you might want `->where()` and not `->get_where()`.  At least, I would give that a try.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In CodeIgniter's Active Record, every method returns the object itself (which allows method chaining) except for `get` and `get_where` which return the result set.

Thus, what you need to do is:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('birth_date', 'ASC')->get_where($this->tbl_name, $where);
```

i.e. The `get_where()` call needs to be the last one. It returns the result set, and so calling `order_by()` after `get_where()` is attempting to call it on the result set which is invalid.

**EDIT**

There are other ways to write this query as well:

```
 $query = $this->db->from($this->tbl_name)->where($where)->order_by('birth_date', 'ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->order_by('birth_date', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get_where($field1, $field2);
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer otherwise it is hard to understand what it does.Even variable name `$field1`,`$filed2` confusing

Comment: order_by needs to be placed before get_where

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('columnName', 'ASC')->get_where('tableName');
return $query->result();
```